# How to get list of commits related to changes in specific directory?

Tags: git

Is it possible to get list of commits only related to changes in specific directory? i.e. my git repo have lost of folders and I need commits that made changes only in specific subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a file or directory as a parameter to `git log` to make it list only commits relevant to it:

```
$ git log -- some_directory
```

This can of course be combined with any other flags or options you normally pass to `git log`. E.g.:

```
$ git log --author=mureinik -p -- some_directory
```